# Login into a webpage with a function and continue my code from there in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I create a function that open a website and login into that same website using my FB credentials and go into my account.

After that, I tried to create a new function to go into my account and start to do other stuffs. the problem is that, after I call my Login function, it open a new webpage and do all the login steps there, and I don't know how to continue accessing it.

My log in function is working perfectly. Opens the webpage, do the login with FB and enter into my account nicely, than when I start to try to click new functions the code stops and give an error.

I was trying to break my code in several steps/functions and calling each one when need it. - one function to log in, other to check my messages, other to delete old messages, etc...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from LogIn import Login_Market

    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    def AutoBid():
        Login_Market()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('__XPAHT__').click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

My function Login_Market is defined in a different file named LogIn.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def Login_Market():
    My_email = "MY_EMAIL@XXX.XX"
    My_pass = "MY_PASSWORD"

    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#FB login
    driver.get(__webSite__)
    main_page = driver.current_window_handle
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("facebook-login-button-icon").click()
    time.sleep(3)

#change browser page
    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        if handle != main_page:
            login_page = handle

#Login FB
    driver.switch_to.window(login_page)
    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(My_email)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]').send_keys(My_pass)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_0"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to.window(main_page)
```

How can I understand how to continue my code from the window that my Login function opened?

Comment: What do you mean by _continue my code from the window that my Login function opened_ ?

Comment: AutoBid function, calls Login_Market function which open a webpage, log-in into the website and select the main page. Than the second line of AutoBid function, should start from where Login Function finished, but the 2nd line: driver.find_element_by_xpath('__XPAHT__').click(), is not being executed in the page that Log-in opened, and i dont know what to do...

Comment: This looks like it might an issue with global variables, no? By the way, you seem to be mixing multiple naming conventions, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.